# Angular: ngModelChange doesn't change value from the dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a drop down implemented as below:

```
    <select (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let quantity of quantities" [ngValue]="quantity">
          {{ quantity }}
        </option>
    </select>
```

The component code is provided:

```
export class ProductItemComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    productItem: Product;

    @Output()
    addProduct: EventEmitter<Product> = new EventEmitter();

    @Output()
    selectedQuantity: EventEmitter<Number> = new EventEmitter();

    quantities: number[] = [];

    constructor(private productService: ProductsService) {
        this.productItem = {
            id: 1,
            name: '',
            price: 0.0,
            url: '',
            description: ''
        };

        this.quantities = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_, i) => i + 1);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    addToCart(p: Product): void {
        this.addProduct.emit(p);
    }

    public onChange(event: any): void {

         const quantity = event.target.value;

         console.log('\n');
         console.log('quantity ' + quantity);
         console.log('\n');

        this.selectedQuantity.emit(quantity);
    }

    showProductDetails(product: Product): void {
        this.productService.setCurrentProduct(product);
    }
}
```

However, if I change the quantity from the drop-down, the value is not updating. How d I fix it?

Edit:

The code works fine if I use `change` in the `<selector>` tag:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let quantity of quantities" [ngValue]="quantity">
          {{ quantity }}
        </option>
    </select>
```

So, I can work, but, I need to understand why the ngModelChange doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For `ngModel` to work, the input need to have a `name` attribute. (You should see some errors in the console)

If the drop-down is not bound to a variable for a two-ways binding, there's no value in using `ngModel` nor `ngModelChange` though.

You should rather use a basic `(change)` event:

```js
(change)="onChange($event)
```

Answer (score 0):

We should have `ngModel` in order to use `ngModelChange` where it actually meant to be.

`change` is regular change detection of the DOM elements in Angular like input, dropdown and radio inputs.

You can get more idea on this with below

- https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#properties
- https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/difference-change-ngmodelchange-angular

Answer (score 0):

Use `(ngModelChange)` with `[(ngModel)]` like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
 <option *ngFor="let quantity of quantities" [ngValue]="quantity">
      {{ quantity }}
 </option>
</select>
```

to ensure `onChange($event)` is called after `[(ngModel)]` updated `selectedValue`.
`(ngModelChange)` is emitted by `[(ngModel)]`after it updated the model.

Comment: `ngValue` is needed to receive the value in the correct type rather than `string` (if using `ngModel`)

Comment: Oh! may be `[value]` could be used as well? :)

Comment: No because `[value]` always produces a string when reading back the value.

Comment: So, I can edit my answer as per your suggestion :)